# Number of hits while loading a webpage?

Tags: java, httpclient, httpurlconnection

While loading a web page I want to calculate number of hits to the server(Number of requests and and number of responses). For example while loading http://www.stackoverflow.com how many times it requests the server and the number of responses form the server, I want that count.
Can anyone help me out please. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thanks for yours answers..
I want to write a program in java to do this task. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Many browsers come with tools that will show you all of the requests going to and responses coming from a particular server. In Chrome you can find it under View > Developer > Developer Tools.

Another alternative is to use a tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) that records all network traffic, and then allows you to filter down to specific host.

[Ngrep](http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/) is a command line alternative to wireshark. Here's the command to see all the relevant requests

```
ngrep -W byline -q "^(GET|POST).*stackoverflow"
```

For more information on ngrep and other related command line tools see [this post](http://www.coderholic.com/invaluable-command-line-tools-for-web-developers/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use FireBug for Firefox and see how many requests are made to that site when you open it in the browser. Other browsers also have similar tools.